# AIR for iOS: download a file (from remote server) and open it with default app

Tags: ios, flash, air

I want my app (AIR app ported on iOS) to be able to show file located on the remote server and open it with default app (if there's one on device). Is it possible (maybe one can somehow use `openWithDefaultApp` here)? And what is the simpliest way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** I succeed with downloading (into `File.documentsDirectory`). I can't force iPad to open downloaded files.

**UPD2:** I tried to use both `openWithDefaultApp` and `NavigateToUrl`.

Comment: navigateToUrl has limited capability from a local application storage directory. There may be a native extension that could do this; however, it would seem your best bet is navigable server resources spawning applications based upon MIME types.

Comment: @JasonSturges, can you please explain what do you mean by `navigable server resources spawning applications`?

Comment: Making a http request to a resource (like a PDF, document, video, etc...) should attempt to load that resource in the correct app to the best of the phone's ability.

Comment: @JasonSturges,actually it just downloads PDF (as if I clicked on link in browser). Probably I should put a header in my `URLRequest`?

Comment: StageWebView may work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the `openWithDefaultApplication` is supported for iOS or Android.

There is a request for this feature at Adobe Ideas:

http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=6B8A5F97-BD20-4CCE-A921-1D6006B4608E

You may be able to use StageWebView, such as for viewing PDF documents:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;

    public class PdfViewer extends Sprite
    {
        public function PdfViewer()
        {
            super();

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            var stageWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
            stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            stageWebView.stage = stage;
            stageWebView.loadURL("document.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jason,So you're trying to say that opening file in default app is not possible by other means?

Comment: Perhaps leveraging native extensions, but I have never attempted that functionality.

Comment: @JasonSturges, I'm very affraid of using ANE